# Особенности верстки страницы для печати

Tags: html, css, media-queries, print

Нужно сделать html-верстку сертификата, который можно будет распечатать в формате A4 и который занимает всего 1 страницу. Хотел уточнить:

1. Сначала делается обычная верстка по ширине страницы, а потом
   стили для печати прописываются в media print? Или обычные стили и
   стили для печати будут идентичны?
2. Верстка делается как для
   обычной страницы или больше как для верстки писем? Можно ли
   использовать флексы и гриды в данном случае?
3. Стили для этой страницы прописывать в общем файле или отдельно?
4. Нужно ли делать адаптив для данной страницы?
5. В сертификате есть пустые поля для
   заполнения. Я так понимаю, что данные для сертификата должны браться
   из личного кабинета и т.п. Нужно еще верстать пустые дивы в которые
   должны подставляться данные?
6. В каких единицах измерения прописывать стили для печати?

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО: Делается верстка страницы для экрана. Для печати в отдельных стилях а) выкидывается все лишнее, б) выкидываются неподдерживаемые вещи, в) делается контент динамической ширины, чтобы подстраивался под ширину области печати, г) делаются стили, управляющие разрывами и переносами контента между страницами (чтобы, например, не разрывало картинки или абзацы).

Например, у вас нормально не распечатаются тени (box-shadow) или некоторые виды бордеров. 
И, да, для А4 система, если не ошибаюсь, считает ширину области печати равной 768 пикселей (независимо от разрешения самой печати). Можете сделать фон страницы из пиксельных линеек (подготовить измерительную картинку) и посмотреть, сколько пикселей влезет в область печати.